# Form validation after drupal_build_form in hook_node_view

Tags: 7, forms, nodes

In hook_node_view of one node I add a node form of a different content type as follows:

```
global $user;
$node_form = (object) array('uid' => $user->uid,
                            'name' => (isset($user->name) ? $user->name : ''),
                            'type' => 'my_type',
                            'language' => LANGUAGE_NONE
                            );
//create form state
$form_state['build_info']['args'] = array($node_form);

form_load_include($form_state, 'inc', 'node', 'node.pages');
$form = drupal_build_form('my_type_node_form', $form_state);

//change default save button
$form['actions']['submit']['#value'] = t("Nice Save");
$form['#validate'][] = 'my_module_my_validate';

//hide few fields
if(!in_array('administrator', $account -> roles)) {
    $form['field_field_1']['#access'] = FALSE;
    $form['field_field_2']['#access'] = FALSE;
    $form['field_field_3']['#access'] = FALSE;
}

$node -> content['my_form'] = $form;
```

All of above works great. Form is nicely displayed, fields are hidden, submit button value is changed and additional validation handler seems to be added correctly as `debug($form['#validate'])` returs:

```
array (
  0 => 'node_form_validate',
  1 => 'my_module_my_validate',
)
```

default validation is trigged as one of the fields in embedded form is required and left empty Drupal as expected returns: `My required filed field is required.` Node is created just fine using this form.

The problem is that for some reason my custom validate handler is not called at all.

```
/*
 *
 */
function my_module_my_validate($form, &$form_state) {
    debug('test');
    form_set_error('', 'error');
}
```

Am I missing something? I could potentially use `hook_form_alter` but I would like to get this working correctly.

Comment: Try adding the validation handler to the button itself. Note how [`form_execute_handlers()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21form.inc/function/form_execute_handlers/7) uses _either_ the button handlers or the form-level ones.

Comment: @Andy do you mean like that: `$form['actions']['submit']['#validate'][]  = 'my_module_my_validate';`

Comment: Yup. No joy? ..

Comment: Unfortunately no...

Comment: Looking again, I suspect you _do_ need a form alter. You're modifying the form array after it's already been built, which includes caching the form and processing the input.

Comment: Note that if you only want to modify the form when it's being shown in that context, you can pass a custom build arg and check for it in the form alter.

Comment: @Andy - that would make sense, however I can hide items and change Submit button value. Wouldn't that not work as well?

Comment: Those are handled at render time, whereas the input processing (and therefore handler execution) are done at form build time.

Comment: Or to put it another way, consider the form returned by `drupal_build_form()` as nothing more than a render array that happens to render a form. If you want a form array proper, you need to get the form via an alter (ie before `drupal_process_form()` is called on it).

Comment: @Andy - thanks a lot for that. I makes perfect sense now. Can you think of a suitable alternative to `drupal_build_form ` that will cover ajax, file upload and will allow to change form directly?

Comment: I don't quite get what the problem is with `drupal_build_form` here?

Comment: done, ps thanks for introducing me to `form_load_include()` (:

Comment: you know that they say - you are learning when teaching

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You do need a form alter. You're modifying the form array after it's already been built, which includes caching the form and processing the input.

> Form is nicely displayed, fields are hidden, submit button value is changed

Those are handled at render time, whereas the input processing (and therefore handler execution) are done at form build time. Or to put it another way, consider the form returned by `drupal_build_form()` as nothing more than a render array that happens to render a form. If you want a form array proper, you need to get the form via an alter (ie before `drupal_process_form()` is called on it).

You can use `hook_form_FORM_ID_alter()` if you want to target just one content type form, or `hook_form_BASE_FORM_ID_alter()` if you want to target multiple types or be dynamic. If you need to know within the form alter whether the form's embedded via a `hook_node_view()` you can pass that state via `$form_state`.